# How to change properties of point tracker without re-initializing tracking?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, tracking, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I am working on point tracker, I know I can set the properties of tracker initilay by using :

```
tracker = vision.PointTracker('NumPyramidLevels',3,'MaxBidirectionalError', 2, 'MaxIterations',30,'BlockSize',[5 5]);
initialize(tracker, points.Location, objectFrame);
```

and then by using step method the tracking is working fine.

my question how to make these properties dynamic during the tracker is working, I used same method inside the while statment as following:

```
while ~isDone(videoFileReader)
    frame = step(videoFileReader);
    [points, validity,scores] = step(tracker, frame);
tracker = vision.PointTracker('NumPyramidLevels',3,'MaxBidirectionalError', 2, 'MaxIterations',30,'BlockSize',[5 5]);
initialize(tracker, points, objectFrame);
end
```

but the problem here that the tracker is initialized again! but I need to continue on the prevouis fram state without initialize the tracking again.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to change those properties?

Comment: @Dima I want to change parameter of MaxBidirectionalError to be changed during tracking, because I need to maximize error when the number of features is small and when the number of features is large I want to decrease the error, So I need to make sure that we don't lose the features while tracking

Comment: Oh, I see...  You may be better off figuring out a way to detect more features, when there are too few left...

Comment: I think to use the setpoint, but this will need to reselect the object by user manually

Comment: What kind of object are you tracking? If it is a face, you can re-detect it automatically using `vision.CascadeObjectDetector`...  See this example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces

Comment: I need to track soccer player

Comment: Try `vision.PeopleDetector`.  Alternatively, if the camera is stationary you can use `vision.ForegroundDetector` to detect all moving objects. Also see this pedestrian tracking example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/tracking-pedestrians-from-a-moving-car.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82240/discussion-between-hanaa-and-dima).

Comment: I think, you could first release the previous tracker, and then initialize...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is "no".

`vision.PointTracker` is a System Object, which is a special kind of MATLAB class. In a System Object, properties may be *tunable* or *non-tunable*. *Non-tunable* properties can only be changed before you call the `step` method of the object for the first time. Currently, all properties of `vision.PointTracker` are non-tunable, which means you cannot change their values inside the loop.